# Custom XML Validator Factory

Tags: xsd, spring-integration, xsd-validation

I'm getting the following error: `src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'common:Email' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.` when my Spring Integration configuration is loaded. All the marshalling-unmarshalling and xml validation is done via Spring Integration configuration

The problem is that I have in my XSDs some references to external XSD and that's why it's failing.

I was thinking if there's a way to override the Jaxp13ValidatorFactory which is throwing the exception in order to make it able to load the external xsds?